# FreqDivider with incorrect test

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity FreqDivider is
port(clkIn  : in  std_logic;
    k      : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      clkOut : out std_logic);
end FreqDivider;

architecture Behavioral of FreqDivider is

signal s_counter : unsigned(31 downto 0);
signal s_halfWay : unsigned(31 downto 0);

begin
s_halfWay <= (unsigned(k) / 2);

process(clkIn)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clkIn)) then
        s_counter <= s_counter + 1;
        if( s_counter = (unsigned(k)-1) ) then
            clkOut <= '0';
            s_counter <= to_unsigned(0,32);
        elsif( s_counter = s_halfWay-1) then
            clkOut <= '1';

        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Hello, so i have this code but I'm testing and the clkOut is always '0' no matter what the input is!
Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a reset in there

Comment: What does your testbench look like?

Comment: The clkOut is always 0 no matter what the input is

Comment: Note Neil_UK's comment. Without initializing s_count it will always be 'U's satisfying neither condition in the inner if statement.

Comment: oh, so do i have to initialize s_counter before the rising edge? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal of type `std_logic` will take an initial value of `'U'`, unless you indicate otherwise. `unsigned` is an array of `std_logic`. You have the line:

```
s_counter <= s_counter + 1;
```

If the counter starts as `"UUUUUU..."`, what does adding one to this mean? You need to initialise the counter to a known state, probably zero.

One option is to add a `reset` input signal to your port list:

```
reset : in std_logic;
```

then change your process to something like this:

```
if (rising_edge(clk)) then
  if (reset = '1') then  -- Synchronous reset
    s_counter <= (others => '0');
  else
    -- Do other things with the counter
  end if;
end if;
```

You could alternatively make the reset asynchronous; personally I avoid asynchronous controls. Once the reset has been correctly asserted, the counter will be in a known state, and you should be able to work with it as you need.

The second option is to simply initialise the counter in its definition:

```
signal s_counter : unsigned(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```